# Why didn't the game save some of my choices?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one, the-walking-dead-season-two

In Season 1, and the first time when Kenny, Lee, Clem, Katya, Duck, and others found the abandoned car with supplies in it, I chose NOT to take it and told Clem that we would be okay without it. However, in a Season 2 flashback it showed that my character took the supplies.

Besides that, back at the house, I chose the option not to eat human meat and told Clem to not eat it, but in Episode 5 the stranger who kidnapped Clementine told me that I forced Clem to eat human meat and said that I gave Clem a hood which belonged to his boy.

I want to play it again because I don't want the next seasons to be influenced by these choices. So can anyone help me fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game is just bugged and it has been bugged since Season 3 came out. For example [here](https://www.giantbomb.com/the-walking-dead/3030-34205/forums/did-anyone-else-have-their-decisions-imported-inco-552469/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWalkingDeadGame/comments/960dlj/walking_dead_collection_choice_glitches/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWalkingDeadGame/comments/960dlj/walking_dead_collection_choice_glitches/). Granted these threads are old but from what you're reporting, a year later and they haven't fixed these issues.

I didn't experience any of the bigger story points being messed up but I noticed lots of smaller choices being wrong. Although I played all seasons together so perhaps the problem occurs only if your saves are older.

You could try starting over but if the TWD collection is still bugged, there's no real guarantee your choices will carry over. You could also use the [Storybuilder](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Story_Builder_(Video_Game)).